# How and where to get feedback on your git repo

Tags: git, github, webpack, repository, boilerplate

I know its not a programming related question but is there anyway on the internet where you can post your git repository and get feedback on it for example how to make it better?

I have [this](https://github.com/touqeerkhan11/The-Ultimate-Boilerplate.git) webpack boilerplate git repository which i want somebody to review and give me some advice like how to make it better for any future projects

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, perhaps.

Comment: That's what friends are for \o/